# How to solve "Undefined reference to function" in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded, eclipse-cdt

I did setup a C project with Eclipse Photon (4.8.0) for developing a program for the ESP-32. I did configure the IDE according to [this official setup instructions](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/get-started/).

Flashing the ESP-32 works fine. But as soon as I try to include header files from a sub folder, I run into troubles. I have set up a very simple project to illustrate the issue. The project consists of `main.c`, `base/test.h` and `base/test.c`, whereas the `test.h` and `test.c` files only contain one function with the signature `void function1(void);`.

When I try to call `function1()` in `main.c`, I get this error in `main.c`:

> Undefined reference to function1()

Please compare to the attached screenshot, where everything is depicted.

How to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not a compiler, but rather a linker error.

Note, with `#include`ing a header file, you only make the external function known to the compiler. You also need to *link* to the external function during the linking stage. Make sure you include the compiled object file that contains `function1` into the link.

Comment: I have the same issue with Eclipse CDT 4.14. How may I instruct eclipse to link the file?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to do proper **linking**.

1. If you are linking with a library, you need to specify:

- The name of the library: `Project\Settings\C C++ General\Paths and Symbols\Libraries`
- Location where the linker should search for this library:
  `Project\Settings\C C++ General\Paths and Symbols\Library Paths`
  **Important**: see Note.

2. If you are linking with object files, add those to:

- `Project\Settings\C C++ Build\Settings\Linker\Miscellaneous\Other objects`

*Note*:

- If your library name is, for example, `libsomething.a`, than you need to specify only `something` as the name; so **omit `lib` prefix and `.a` suffix**.
- If your library is not prefixed with `lib`, then you need to add its **name prefixed with `:`**. For example, `something.a` should be added as `:something.a`.